# Fixing wiggly door handle

Tags: doors

I'm having a hard time fixing my front door handle which has been quite wiggly.

I thought the problem was within the mechanism of the multipoint lock that the spindle connecting the two handles goes through. So I changed the whole multipoint lock (had a spare), but the problem persisted.

The spindle is 8mm thick and [the dimensions of the hole in the multipoint lock that the handles go through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8zsZ.jpg) also suggest it's 8mm.

Is the hole cutout on the wooden door too big? I'm out of ideas and wanted to check here.

- [Link to plate part](https://www.tenhulscher.nl/deurbeslag/rozet/zwart/gpf8100-02-rozet-50x50x8mm-zwart)

Photos to further demonstrate:

[image: Bearing plate]
[image: Handle plate]

Comment: I'd expect the spindle to have some play. That's normal. It needs some pivot to avoid binding. How does the handle attach? Are you sure you're not missing a plastic washer or something?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Handles attach with a grub screw going towards the spindle. 

I thought that the nylon washers to reduce wear from the handle going against the plate? Would they also help with the wiggle?

Comment: They do in the sense that you can push the handle tight, secure it, and not have metal-to-metal contact. Is there flexibility in the handle's position, or does the set screw ride in a groove?

Comment: Yeah, the handle has no flexibility. The screws ride into the groove. I think I'll need to fill the hole made in the wooden door.

Comment: That should have no bearing on this problem. No door hardware I've ever installed relies on interior wood for stability, and I wouldn't expect it to be a remedy here. A manufacturer product link for the assembly would be helpful, or even some photos of your hardware.

Comment: Hey isherwood, 

After more digging in, I realize that the problem is that the plate that the handles are going through is missing a piece. I edited the original post with a photo of the original part and a link to it and what mine currently looks like so you can check.

Comment: That 3rd pic does look like the bearing plate that should hold the handle spindle. If it's missing, that would go a long way toward explaining why your handle wobbles. We can't tell, though, from the pics provided if it is missing. If you've determined that this is the problem, write it up as an answer (self-answers are accepted and normal here), and include a pic showing where it was missing and how you've installed it. That may help someone else with the same/similar problem. It would be nice if you could include the exact model of your lockset and of the replacement part, too.

Comment: Updated the post to show the missing part better. I'll order the piece and see if that fixes it. If so, will post an answer, thanks!

Comment: Now that makes a lot more sense. Congrats.